# AssertionError: image must be rgb 224x224 ((224, 224, 4))

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to run an open-sourced inference code for predicting polygons given bounding boxes called [Polygon-RNN++](https://github.com/fidler-lab/polyrnn-pp)

I'm trying to run on my own image which I have cropped to (224,224) but I'm still getting assertion errors like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-224b99f63642> in <module>
      4 image_np = skimage.transform.resize(image_np,(224,224))
      5 #image_np = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
----> 6 preds = [model.do_test(polySess, image_np, top_k) for top_k in range(_FIRST_TOP_K)]
      7 
      8 # sort predictions based on the eval score to pick the best.

<ipython-input-8-224b99f63642> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 image_np = skimage.transform.resize(image_np,(224,224))
      5 #image_np = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
----> 6 preds = [model.do_test(polySess, image_np, top_k) for top_k in range(_FIRST_TOP_K)]
      7 
      8 # sort predictions based on the eval score to pick the best.

~/Desktop/polyrnn/src/PolygonModel.py in do_test(self, sess, input_images, first_top_k)
     61         Return polygon
     62         """
---> 63         assert input_images.shape[1:] == (224, 224, 3), 'image must be rgb 224x224 (%s)' % str(input_images.shape)
     64         pred_dict = sess.run(
     65             self._prediction(),

AssertionError: image must be rgb 224x224 ((224, 224, 4))
```

My image is a normal RGB image, why is its shape (224,224,4) and how can I reshape it to (224,224,3)?

Comment: My guess is the image has an alpha channel, which means your source image format is in RGBA (4 channels), you would need to convert it into RGB and then it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are four channels, your source image is in `RGBA` format where the last channel is the alpha/transparency channel. You can slice the array to isolate the `RGB` channels

```
remove_alpha_from_image = image[:,:,:3]
```

Another way to do it is like this

```
remove_alpha_from_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```